# Is it possible to print or echo php code onto a php document?

Tags: php, printing, echo

I was wondering if it's possible to print or echo out code onto a PHP document so that it prints different code all the time? So basically I want to create a different button for each punishment displayed, but with that button comes with a form with the ID of that button, how can I activate some sort of code using that ID in order to do whatever...

```
                                            print " <div class='modal fade' id='pun-$id' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='$id' aria-hidden='true'>";
                                        print "     <div class='modal-dialog'>";
                                        print "         <div class='modal-content'>";
                                        print "             <div class='modal-header'>";
                                        print "                 <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>";
                                        print "                 <h4 class='modal-title'>Punishment record of $username</h4>";
                                        print "             </div>";
                                        print "             <div class='modal-body'>";
                                        print "                 <ul class='list-group'>";
                                        print "                     <li class='list-group-item'>Punishment ID: </br><div class='well well-sm'><p>"; print $row[0]; print "</p></div></li>";
                                        print "                     <li class='list-group-item'>Punishment Type: </br><div class='well well-sm'><p>"; print $row[11]; print "</p></div></li>";
                                        print "                     <li class='list-group-item'>Date Punished: </br><div class='well well-sm'><p>"; print $row[5]; print "</p></div></li>";
                                        print "                     <li class='list-group-item'>Punished until: </br><div class='well well-sm'><p>"; print $row[6]; print "</p></div></li>";
                                        print "                     <li class='list-group-item'>Punished by: </br><div class='well well-sm'><p>"; print $punisher[0]; print "</p></div></li>";
                                        print "                     <li class='list-group-item'>Reason: </br><div class='well well-sm' style='height: 150px; overflow: auto;'><p>"; print $row[3]; print "</p></div></li>";
                                        print "                     <li class='list-group-item'>Link to the evidence: </br><div class='well well-sm'><p>"; print $row[4]; print "</p></div></li>";
                                        print "                 </ul>";
                                        print "                 <hr>";
                                        print "                 <ul class='list-group'>";
                                        print "                     <li class='list-group-item'>Revoked Reason: </br><div class='well well-sm'><p>"; print $row[9]; print "</p></div></li>";
                                        print "                     <li class='list-group-item'>Revoked by: </br><div class='well well-sm'><p>"; print $row[10]; print "</p></div></li>";
                                        if($row[8] == 0 && $_permission >= $_SETTINGS['permission_required-revoke-punishment']) {
                                            print "                     <button data-toggle='modal' href='#revoke-$id' style='padding: 10px; border: 0; width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;' class='btn btn-primary' data-dismiss='modal'>Revoke Punishment</button>";     
                                        } else {
                                            print "                     <button data-toggle='modal' href='#revoke-$id' style='padding: 10px; border: 0; width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;' class='btn btn-primary disabled' data-dismiss='modal'>Revoke Punishment</button>";
                                        }
                                        print "                 </ul>";
                                        print "             </div>";
                                        print "         </div>";
                                        print "     </div>";
                                        print " </div>";

                                        $code = '<?php 
                                            if(isset($_POST[\'revoke_pun-$id\'])) { 
                                                $reason = $_POST[\'reason-$id\'];
                                                $reason = stripslashes($reason;
                                                $reason = $connection->real_escape_string($reason);
                                                $command = "UPDATE $punishments SET REVOKED=1, REVOKE_REASON=$reason, REVOKER_ID=$uid WHERE PUNISHMENT_ID = $id;";
                                                mysqli_query($connection, $command) or die (mysqli_error());
                                            }    
                                        ?>';

                                        print "<div class='modal fade' id='revoke-$id' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='revoke-$id' aria-hidden='true'>";
                                        print "    <div class='modal-dialog'>";
                                        print "        <div class='modal-content'>";
                                        print "            <div class='modal-header'>";
                                        print "                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>";
                                        print "                <h4 class='modal-title'>Revoke Punishment</h4>";
                                        print "            </div>";
                                        print "            <div class='modal-body' style='padding-bottom: 50px;'>";
                                        print "                <form role='form' method='post'>";
                                        print "                    <textarea style='resize:vertical; min-height: 100px; margin-bottom: 10px;' class='form-control' placeholder='Reason(s) as to why you are revoking this punishment...' name='reason-$id'></textarea>";
                                        print "                    <button style='width: 50%; float: right;' class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' name='revoke_pun-$id'>Revoke Punishment</button>";
                                        print "                </form>";
                                        print "            </div>";
                                        print "        </div>";
                                        print "    </div>";
                                        print "</div>";
```

Comment: This is possible via `eval()` but by all means not advisable! Think about what exactly it is you are trying to achieve and check out template engines, MVC principles, etc. that are usually used in such situations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean generating a different PHP file? Yes, you can: instead of echo/print, just write the contents to a file ([file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents)).

However, I have the feeling that, while this answers your question, your question may be the wrong one. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well, Basically I'm loading punishments from a SQL table, but I have a button which says Revoke Punishment, then It revokes the punishment with the id, however the id could be different for different people. I.e user 1 could have punishment id, 1, 6, 205. So how would I go about create custom code so that I can do this?

Comment: Why don't you just add a hidden field in the form? Like "punishment_id"... I don't see reasons for what you're trying to do